# Removing whitespaces inside a string

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a string  `lots\t of\nwhitespace\r\n`  which I have simplified but I still need to get rid of the other spaces in the string.

```
QString str = "  lots\t of\nwhitespace\r\n ";
str = str.simplified();
```

I can do this `erase_all(str, " ");` in boost but I want to remain in qt.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
str = str.simplified();
str.replace( " ", "" );
```

The first changes all of your whitespace characters to a single instance of ASCII 32, the second removes that.

Comment: @noone in that case you should probably make a simple test case and report a bug, because according to the documentation it still ought to.

Comment: sorry. My bad . I had not included QString

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
str.replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score 14):

**Option 1**:

Simplify the white space, then remove it

Per the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#simplified)

> [`QString::simplified`] Returns a string that has whitespace removed from the start and the end, and that has each sequence of internal whitespace replaced with a single space.

Once the string is simplified, the white spaces can easily be removed.

```
str.simplified().remove(' ')
```

**Option 2**:

Use a `QRegExp` to capture all types of white space in `remove`.

```
QRegExp space("\\s");
str.remove(space);
```

**Notes**

- The OPs string has white space of different types (tab, carriage return, new line), all of which need to be removed. This is the tricky part.
- `QString::remove` was introduced in Qt 5.6; prior to 5.6 removal can be achieved using `QString::replace` and replacing the white space with an empty string `""`.

Comment: Is simplified() necessary here? Surely remove(" ") will do the job?

Comment: @IronAttorney Depending on the approach, yes. I've added clarification to my answer and an alternative solution that does not require `simplified`.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the call to `simplified()` with a regex:

```
str.replace(QRegularExpression("\\s+"), QString());
```

I don't have measured which method is faster. I guess this regex would perform worse.